# Transforming XML into MS Excel XML - formula syntax

Tags: xml, xslt, excel-formula

I am transforming some XML to view in MS Excel. There is a very good reference on how to create the schema - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx. This [blog](http://www.openscope.net/2010/02/09/transforming-xml-into-ms-excel-xml/) is also useful.

I am having trouble inserting a formula into a cell, so:
    `<Cell ss:Index="2" ss:Formula="=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])">` 
         `<Data ss:Type="Number"></Data>`
       `</Cell>`
is pretty straightforward. This will sum the values in the row 3 rows above to the row 1 above.

However, the formula I need (in A1 style format, rather than R1C1) is **`=SUMIF(A:A,"Assignments",B:B)`**.

I have tried many options, including

- `ss:Formula="=SUMIF(C[-1]:C[-1],Assignments,C[0]:C[0])"` but the definition of the cell equals **`=SUMIF(A:A,Assignments,B:B)`** in this case.
- `ss:Formula="=SUMIF(C[-1]:C[-1],"Assignments",C[0]:C[0])"` but the workbook becomes corrupt and won't open.
- `ss:Formula="=SUMIF(C[-1]:C[-1],'Assignments',C[0]:C[0])"` but the definition of the cell equals **`0`** in this case.

The quotation marks are causing a problem. Does anyone know the correct syntax to get the required formula insert into a cell?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to be aware of XML document escape characters.
[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

The line in the code needed was:

`ss:Formula="=SUMIF(C1:C1, &quot;Assignments&quot;,C[0]:C[0])"`